# How do you define trait using Fabrication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, fabrication-gem

I am learning how to use [fabrication](http://www.fabricationgem.org/#getting-started) in `Rails` and we have decided to replace all our `factory_girl` code with fabrication.

Suppose we have this code in `factory_girl`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
  trait(:no_credits) { credits 0 }
  trait(:with_credits) { credits 300 }
```

How will you define this in Fabrication? I have gone through their website but couldn't find anything regarding this. Will appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that your are looking for [Fabricator inheritance](https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication-site/blob/master/source/index.markdown#inheritance), this is what the docs says:

You can inherit attributes from other fabricators by using the `:from` attribute.

```
Fabricator(:llc, from: :company) do
  type "LLC"
end
```

Setting the `:from` option will inherit the class and all the attributes from the named Fabricator.

You can also explicitly specify the class being fabricated with the `:class_name` parameter.

```
Fabricator(:llc, class_name: :company) do
  type "LLC"
end
```

Comment: Are you sure about inheritance? Because `trait` is more like defining custom attributes. In my example, the `user` will have `credits` 0. I don't think inheritance is the right approach.

Comment: You can define the defaults on the base class, each inherited class will override some of those default values. I think it will behave as you expect. Give it a try and tell me if it worked :)

Comment: In factory girls, we also have `after(:create)` that we can use with `trait`. Do you know anyway I can do something similar with fabrication?

Comment: Take a look to callbacks https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication-site/blob/master/source/index.markdown#callbacks

Comment: `Traits` are not models so you cannot use `Fabricator` with them. I just realized this