# How to group attributes in Fabrication like using trait in Factory_Girl

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, fabrication-gem

Could you anyone through code show me how we can convert this particular `factory_girl` code in using `Fabrication`?

```
factory :user do
  name "Friendly User"
  login { name }

  trait :male do
    name   "John Doe"
    gender "Male"
    login { "#{name} (M)" }
  end

  trait :female do
    name   "Jane Doe"
    gender "Female"
    login { "#{name} (F)" }
  end

  trait :admin do
    admin true
    login { "admin-#{name}" }
  end

  factory :male_admin,   traits: [:male, :admin]   # login will be "admin-John Doe"
  factory :female_admin, traits: [:admin, :female] # login will be "Jane Doe (F)"
end
```

If you see this [Trait in Fabrication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065015/how-do-you-define-trait-using-fabrication) `inheritance` is one of the method here but the problem is we cannot define `Fabricator` for it since they are not `models`. Can anyone show me how can we group attributes in `Fabrication`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You express it like this in fabrication:

```
Fabricator :user do
  admin false
  gender 'Female'
  name "Friendly User"
  login do |attrs|
    if attrs[:admin]
      "admin-#{attrs[:name]}"
    else
      "#{attrs[:name]} (#{attrs[:gender][0]})"
    end
  end
end

Fabricator(:female_admin, from: :user) do
  admin true
end

Fabricator(:male_admin, from: :female_admin) do
  gender 'Male'
end
```